# Is an equivalence class same as residue class?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, equivalence-relations, congruences

So my teacher's notes say this:

> An equivalence class consists of those integers which have the same
>   remainder on division by n. They are also known as "congruence classes
>   modulo n"

Since no example was stated, I decided to make up my own. Let n = 2. I took a series of numbers from 0 to 10 to put them into "equivalence classes" and here is what I ended up with:

{***Remainder = 0*** {0,2,4,6,8,10} , ***Remainder = 1*** {1,3,5,7,9}}

I do not know whether it is right or not. based on the definition it is right, I suppose.

Here is what the notes say about residue class:

> The set of all the integers congruent to modulo n is called residue class [a]

---

My understanding is that "equivalence classes" are formed based on what 'input' has been provided, in my case 0 to 10. Residue classes, on the other hand, will contain all the possible inputs that would have remainder either 0 or 1 (because I chose n =2).

**Am I right?**

Comment: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Residue_Class

Comment: Residue classes are just special types of equivalence classes: images of elements (of algebraic structures) under mod maps. Equivalence classes are collections of elements that are related by an equivalence relation, which doesn't presuppose any binary operations or whatnot.

Comment: @anon Ok ! That simplifies it :)

Comment: And mostly for historical reasons, congruence class exists as another name for equivalence class. An equivalence relation is sometimes called a congruence.